# nodejs load file

Tags: javascript, node.js

I want to load test.txt with nodejs.

```
var fs = require('fs');
fs.readFile('./test.txt', function (err, data) {
  if (err) {
    throw err; 
  }
  console.log(data);
});
```

The path of the server is `C:\server\test\server.js`. The test.txt is located in the same directory, but I get this error: `Error: ENOENT, no such file or directory 'C:\Users\User\test.txt'`

Answer (score 92, accepted):

Paths in Node are resolved relatively to the current working directory. Prefix your path with `__dirname` to resolve the path to the location of your Node script.

```
var fs = require('fs');
fs.readFile( __dirname + '/test.txt', function (err, data) {
  if (err) {
    throw err; 
  }
  console.log(data.toString());
});
```

Comment: I am getting `ReferenceError: __dirname is not defined`. Is it because I sould manually define `var __dirname = '/the/path/'` ?

Comment: @myfirsttime1 `__dirname` only works in Node scripts, not in the REPL.

Answer (score 21):

With Node 0.12, it's possible to do this synchronously now:

```
  var fs = require('fs');
  var path = require('path');

  // Buffer mydata
  var BUFFER = bufferFile('../test.txt');

  function bufferFile(relPath) {
    return fs.readFileSync(path.join(__dirname, relPath)); // zzzz....
  }
```

`fs` is the file system.  [readFileSync()](https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_fs_readfilesync_filename_options) returns a Buffer, or string if you ask.

`fs` correctly assumes relative paths are a security issue.  `path` is a work-around.

To load as a string, specify the encoding:

```
return fs.readFileSync(path,{ encoding: 'utf8' });
```

Answer (score 6):

You should use `__dirname` to get the directory name *the file is located* instead of the current working directory:

```
fs.readFile(__dirname + "/test.txt", ...);
```

Answer (score 3):

Use `path` and `fs`:

```
const fs = require("fs");
const pth = require("path");
```

Sync:

```
let data = fs.readFileSync(pth.join(__dirname,"file.txt"));
console.log(data + "");
```

A-Sync:

```
fs.readFile(pth.join(__dirname,"file.txt"), (err, data) => {
    console.log(data + "");
});
```

And that; If you need to read the file continuously and send it to the client and the file size is not large, you may be able to keep a copy of it:

```
const exp = require("express");
const app = exp();
const fs = require("fs");
const pth = require("path");

let file = "";
app.get("/file", (q, r) => {
    if (file === "")
        file = fs.readFileSync(pth.join(__dirname,"file.txt")) + "";

    r.writeHead(200, { "Content-Type": "text/plain" });
    r.write(file);
    r.end();
});
```

Answer (score 1):

so if it is in the same directory just do this

```
 fs.readFile(__dirname+'/foo.txt',function(e,d){console.log(d)})
```

Comment: Rob it totally does .. just did it in node terminal

Comment: Create a `x.js` at `/tmp/x/x.js`. Put the OPs code in it. Also create `/tmp/x/test.txt`. Now, set your working dir to `/tmp` (eg. `cd /tmp`) and use `node x/x.js` or `node /tmp/x/x.js` --> `Error: ENOENT, no such file or directory 'test.txt'`

Comment: Your original answer was effectively the same code as the OP has (which doesn't work), why the argument lol

Answer (score 0):

If it's in same directory it should work.  I have tested with the same code, with a file `name.txt` and it's working fine:

```
var fs = require('fs');
fs.readFile('./test.txt', function (err, data) {
  if (err) {
    throw err;
  }
  console.log(data.toString());
});
```