# Open file on windows using nodeJS/AngularJS

Tags: javascript, node.js, angularjs, express

I have a problem on opening files on windows.
These files (.pdf, .doc, .xlsx, .png, .....) are on the server computer: B where my REST application (node, Expres, angularJS) is deployed.
The client computer is rated A.

To open any file, I used this: 
require ('child_process'). exec (' start '"' + pathOfFile);

Except that this opens the file on the computer B. And I want the file to be open on the computer A few be the way.

Someone would have any idea ?

Thank you

Comment: Someone would you have an idea about my problem?

Answer (score 0):

I can't add a comment (50 rep point).

If I understand you correctly you are trying to download a file that is on a REST server? if so, try using a GET method on your client and use File System library on your node application to actually load the file. like here - [example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9890473/nodejs-load-file).

Comment: Thank you Dima Shivrin, it helped me a lot.

Comment: Glad to help! Please mark a helpful answer to close this topic