# How to loop inside folder to get certain ext files in Nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js, loops, nodes, node-modules

I have bunch of `settings.js` files where i have `const item` in a folder called components folder, i want to create a nodejs function so that it finds all the `settings.js` files and get all items and console logs them is it possible? if yes then how

Comment: use fs.. can you show your attempt, directory structure and contents of a settings.js file and expected output. Your question is not that clear, you can only have a single settings.js file in a folder

Comment: my Folder structure is:

```bash
├── components
│   ├── Atoms
│   │   ├── Paragraph
│   │   │   ├── Paragraph.jsx
│   │   │   ├── Paragraph.module.scss
│   │   │   ├── settings.js
│   │   ├── Title
│   │   │   ├── Title.jsx
│   │   │   ├── Title.module.scss
│   │   │   ├── settings.js
│   ├── Molecules
│   │   ├── GenericAligned
│   │   │   ├── GenericAligned.jsx
│   │   │   ├── GenericAligned.module.scss
│   │   │   ├── settings.js
```
I havent started attempt yet

Comment: you should add it to your question. Also you need to do some research and make an attempt, here is a starting point [nodejs load file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9890473/nodejs-load-file)